# Codeigniter and i18n's 3rd segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I have a problem about i18n-codeigniter integration. I integrated i18n my last project today. I had some custom routes before i18n. Now I changed them according to i18n route style. But I have some problem with 3rd segments.
I mean, I have this routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['^(tr|en)/hakkimizda'] = 'Bilgi/Hakkimizda';
$route['^(tr|en)/kampanyalar'] = 'Bilgi/Kampanyalar';
$route['^(tr|en)/haberler'] = 'Haberler';
$route['^(tr|en)/kampanyalar/(.+)$'] = 'Bilgi/Kampanyalar/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/haberler/(:any)'] = 'Haberler/HaberDetay/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler'] = 'Urunler';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$2';
$route['^(tr|en)/kesif-talebi'] = "Iletisim/Kesif_Talebi";
$route['^(tr|en)/iletisim'] = "Iletisim";
$route['^tr$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^en'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

some links are working perfectly.When I enter to http://webadress.com/en/urunler that is working perfect but when i enter http://webadress.com/en/urunler/kategori/parameter that gives me blank page...

How can i fix that problem?
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (any:) route is taking precedence.

Try switching the order of:

```
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$2';
```

to

```
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$2';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$1';
```

From the CI docs:

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will
>   always take precedence over lower ones.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Swap these two lines and it should be fine

```
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$2';
```

to

```
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$2';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$1';
```

Comment: my guess its because of this `$route['^(tr|en)/urunler'] = 'Urunler';` which might conflicting with routes below. try to put it after these routes

Comment: I tried it also but not work.Lastly, I tried this.This makes urun detay page perfect but kategori pages alredy wrong.

`$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Detay/$2';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler/kategori/(:any)'] = 'Urunler/Kategori/$1';
$route['^(tr|en)/urunler'] = 'Urunler';`